# Using reference file to find desired data in another file - Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, comparison

I used a Perl script to compare two arrays and retrieve data of interest. Now I want to use that list of retrieved data to get desired information from another list, using only the first part as an identifier but pulling all the information in that line.

Example data:

Reference:

```
apple           
orange          
pear
```

Search list:

```
apple 439

plum 657

orange 455
```

Result:

```
apple 439

orange 455
```

I've tried doing this with `Array::Compare` but haven't had any luck as it compares the entire line not just the first portion.

Thanks!

## EDIT: Thanks to DVK I now have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

#Convert the first file into an array of keys @keys

my @keys = read_file('Matching_strains.txt');

#Convert the second file into an array of lines @lines2

my @lines = read_file('output2.txt');

#Convert that array of lines into a hash using map and split

my %data = map { split(/\s+/, $, 2) } @lines; # 2 limits # of entries

#Get a list of data for which keys are in the first list

my %final = map { exists $data{$_} ? ( $_=>$data{$_} ) : () } @keys;

#Print that hash out

print "%final\n";
```

But I'm getting a number found where operator expected for the my %data, I've consulted perldoc but I'm not sure what number its referring to.
Thanks!

Comment: Convert your search list into a hash, e.g. `apple => 439, plum => 657` (use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)) and it'll be trivial.

Comment: yeah, the issue is that the list is 2038 lines long, is there a fast way to convert it into a hash.

Comment: The number is the 2 in `$, 2` which by default is `undef 2` as `$,` is the output field separator. It should be `$_, 2`

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing should achieve what you're after:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $file1, '<', 'in.txt' or die $!;

open my $file2, '<', 'in.2.txt' or die $!;

my (%keys, %data);

while(<$file1>){
    chomp;
    $keys{$_} = 1;
}

while(<$file2>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split/\s/;
    $data{$split[0]} = $split[1];
}

foreach (keys %keys){
    print "$_ $data{$_}\n" if exists $data{$_};
}
```

---

```
apple 439
orange 455
```

Comment: Why put `@file1` into a hash only to iterate the keys?

Answer (score 1):

- Convert the first file into an array of keys `@keys`

  Left as excercise for the reader
- Convert the second file into an array of lines `@lines2`

  Left as excercise for the reader
- Convert that array of lines into a hash using `map` and `split`

  `my %data = map { split(/\s+/, $, 2) } @lines; # 2 limits # of entries`
- Get a list of data for which keys are in the first list

  `my %final = map { exists $data{$_} ? ( $_=>$data{$_} ) : () } @keys;`
- Print that hash out

Comment: Thanks for the help! For some I'm getting a number found where operator expected for the my %data line, any ideas. My code is added as an edit

Comment: @AJAL I'll take a look but you definitely need to chomp off the newlines off of keys

Comment: The `$` in `split(/\s+/, $, 2)` should be `$_`